# How to switch to another local view from CCoeControl object in Symbian

Tags: view, symbian, switch-statement

My GUI application has two views, First view has a ListBox control - Derived from CCoeControl - and from this object I want to switch to the second view, How can I do this ?

In other words, When user click ListBox Item ...the second view appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your 'views' are derived from CAknView.
Code From this [link](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/S60_application_views)

```
const TUid KDemo1ViewId = { 1 }; // UID of the first view
AppUI()->ActivateLocalViewL(KDemo1ViewId); // activate view 1
```

Also find these links very useful.[Getting a pointer to AppUI](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS000848_-_Getting_a_pointer_to_CAknViewAppUi_or_CAknView)

[Getting a Pointer to a View](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS000042_-_How_can_I_get_a_pointer_from_a_container_to_a_view?)

Edit :

```
CYourApplicationAppUi* appui = (static_cast<CYourApplicationAppUi*>(iEikonEnv>AppUi())); 
// Get the view you want CSomeView* view = (CSomeView*)appui->View(TUid::Uid(ESomeViewId))
```

Comment: Many thanks, But I'm calling the second view from an object derived from CcoeControl not CAknView. How can I do this ?

Comment: CYourApplicationAppUi* appui = (static_cast<CYourApplicationAppUi*>(iEikonEnv->AppUi()));
// Get the view you want
CSomeView* view = (CSomeView*)appui->View(TUid::Uid(ESomeViewId))

Comment: Many thanks for this great help, it woks great. But why the need for the second line (CSomeView*view ....) ?

Comment: Sometimes you don't have a pointer to the 2nd view. You only have the Uid for the view. In this case you can get the Pointer to that view using that method.

Comment: Many thanks Abhijith for your great help, it's really appreciated.